# How to get to the strange tag inside a complicated html script?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to get to the content of all of the tags (aria-label) that are within complicated HTML strings:

```
    <a href="https://www.wtp.waw.pl/rozklady-jazdy/?wtp_dt=2021-12-25&amp;wtp_md=3&amp;wtp_ln=23" class="timetable-button timetable-button-tile " aria-label="Tramwaj - Linia: 23 , Utrudnienia w ruchu"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 36 36" aria-hidden="true">
<path class="i-fg" fill="#FFF"SVG CODE"></path>
</svg><span aria-hidden="true">23</span></a>
```

I created a python script that according to my knowledge should work, but it doesn't do anything (doesn't throw any error either). I am missing something that doesn't look that big... Please help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://www.wtp.waw.pl/rozklady-jazdy/?fbclid=IwAR3oq9mYmn_LKFljiyP2_MkG1r3FHRgZLQdNvis_48nPccaJ6EO3MXb3QLY'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find_all('a', {'aria-label'})
for i in data:
    print(i["aria-label"])
```

Print content of the HTML string used as an example:

```
"Tramwaj - Linia: 23 , Utrudnienia w ruchu"
```

Comment: what's the actual url?

Comment: It’s hard to do without the url. The content could be dynamic or you could be banned from scraping the website, etc. please include both the url and the print(response.content)

Comment: Sorry @QHarr, the url is: https://www.wtp.waw.pl/rozklady-jazdy/?fbclid=IwAR3oq9mYmn_LKFljiyP2_MkG1r3FHRgZLQdNvis_48nPccaJ6EO3MXb3QLY

Comment: Added print content, @KeeganM

Comment: The example HTML is not valid.  is there an extra `SVG CODE"` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem was the way bs4 loads and stores the data. I was able to reproduce the intended output with the following code:

```python
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url ='https://www.wtp.waw.pl/rozklady-jazdy/?fbclid=IwAR3oq9mYmn_LKFljiyP2_MkG1r3FHRgZLQdNvis_48nPccaJ6EO3MXb3QLY'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find_all('a')
for i in data:
    if "aria-label=" in str(i):
        print(i["aria-label"])
```

In the case you want to further narrow your results, add additional logic in the for loop to check for criteria!